# My Theme is responsive but my description is not mobile friendly why?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have my whole site responsive but the data i have copied from the vendor site is not responsive i dont know why i have now copied 200 products and not willing to delete and do the work again.

Can anyone guide me my site when viewed in mobile the data gets outside the screen and is being cropped rather then being mobile friendly.

Link is : http://octa.pk/product/unifi-voip-phone-executive-ubnt-unifi-voip-in-pakistan/

Comment: Did you edited the `.comContent` HTML all manually? For 200+ products?

Comment: Probably because you copied over all the inline styles (maybe from a rich text editor?). You should remove those or move them to a stylesheet so you can add media queries and make them mobile friendly. inline styles are not mobile friendly. you can override them with `!important` though

Comment: @muhammad Try my solution added below.

Comment: i copy pasted the items via GUI i am not much of a tech guy so dont know if the CSS was copied along or not. how do i remove it?

Answer (score 1):

I found that your description div has Width in element style, which might be coming from Javascript. An Easy and non-tested fix would be adding below CSS. ( Note: It's example CSS that fixes the main issue. )

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .comContent {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .comProductFeature__content.col--lg12 {
    max-width: 100%;
  }

  .js-waypoints-center.row.comProductFeature.comProductFeature--center.unifi-voip-executive-scalable-system-management.js-animate-slide-up {
    padding: 0 10px !important;
  }
}
```

Check fix width here
https://nimb.ws/WHI1GY, Anyway, If you have used the same classes to all 200 Products this will fix it.

> If you have copy-pasted these HTML from somewhere, You will have to go through all of the product pages and need to write more CSS code. As Above code is just an example to fix it.

Hope, This helps you.

Comment: Sir thanks for the help , it did make the first paragraph normal but i have 2 issues.
1) Where do i put this code ? when i try to put it in the style.css of the child theme it does nothing.
2) Apart from that the lower data is still not adjusted to the width. Attaching screenshots for you.
https://pasteboard.co/Iu2jnYv.png

https://pasteboard.co/Iu2jz9h.png

Comment: @MuhammadAsim As I mentioned, It's just an example code. You will have to write more CSS code to fix all of the style issues. If you have not expertise in CSS, you can hire someone to do it. :)